# Get a sorted list from a Map via Stream API

Tags: java, collections, java-stream

I am trying to achieve the following scenario with the `Stream API` but with no success.

I have the following graph. The key is the name of the person and the set has the name of friends of the person (key).

```
Map<String, Set<String>> fooGraph
```

I want to have a sorted ArrayList based on the number of friends (popularity), a person has.

For example,

this is the `fooGraph` with its values

```
x -> a,b,c

y -> a

z -> a,b,c,d,e,f

t -> a,b,c,d
```

and at the end of the day, I want to have a list based on the popularity of a person. The list should look like the following

```
z, t, x, y
```

How can it be achieved with `Stream API`?

Comment: Why should one use the Steam API? Just use a `TreeMap` with an appropriate `Comparator`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
List<String> sorted = fooGraph.entrySet()
        .stream()
        .sorted(Comparator.comparing(e -> e.getValue().size(), Comparator.reverseOrder()))
        .map(Map.Entry::getKey)
        .collect(Collectors.toList());
```

Comment: Runs like butter..  I have another sub-question. If two person has a same number of friends, how do this code behave? First come, first served?

Comment: @AdInfinitum Only if it's an ordered map, such as `LinkedHashMap`. Otherwise there's no concept of "first".